# Find the maximum possible value

Tags: maximum-principle

Help me to find the maximum value of $T$ with $x, y, z \in \Bbb{R_+}$
$$T=\frac{x^3y^4z^3}{(x^4+y^4)(xy+z^2)^3}+\frac{y^3z^4x^3}{(y^4+z^4)(yz+x^2)^3}+\frac{z^3x^4y^3}{(z^4+x^4)(zx+y^2)^3}$$
Thanks :D

Comment: It's symmetric in the three variables. If you know there's a unique maximum, I believe you can use that symmetry to your advantage.

Comment: I would see @jdc 's comment and raise him the use of monotonicity along those lines of symmetry

Comment: I call. [and some more characters]

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: first let $$\frac{x^3y^4z^3}{(x^4+y^4)(xy+z^2)^3}=a\\ \frac{y^3z^4x^3}{(y^4+z^4)(yz+x^2)^3}=b\\ \frac{z^3x^4y^3}{(z^4+x^4)(zx+y^2)^3}=c$$then using *HM-GM-AM-QM Inequalities* you get
$$\frac{\frac{x^3y^4z^3}{(x^4+y^4)(xy+z^2)^3}+\frac{y^3z^4x^3}{(y^4+z^4)(yz+x^2)^3}+\frac{z^3x^4y^3}{(z^4+x^4)(zx+y^2)^3}}{3} = \frac{a+b+c}{3} \le \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}}$$
Moreover the maximum of $\frac{a+b+c}{3}$ is obtained if and only if $a=b=c$ and $\frac{a+b+c}{3} = \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}}$. Finally you need to solve
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^3y^4z^3}{(x^4+y^4)(xy+z^2)^3}=\frac{y^3z^4x^3}{(y^4+z^4)(yz+x^2)^3}\\
\frac{y^3z^4x^3}{(y^4+z^4)(yz+x^2)^3}=\frac{z^3x^4y^3}{(z^4+x^4)(zx+y^2)^3}\\
\frac{z^3x^4y^3}{(z^4+x^4)(zx+y^2)^3}=\frac{x^3y^4z^3}{(x^4+y^4)(xy+z^2)^3}
\end{cases}
But since it's a symmetrical system, the solution is $x=y=z$, thus $$\frac{x^3y^4z^3}{(x^4+y^4)(xy+z^2)^3} = \frac{x^3x^4x^3}{(x^4+x^4)(x^2+x^2)^3}=\frac{1}{16}$$
Finally the maximum possible value of $T$ is
$$T=\frac{x^3y^4z^3}{(x^4+y^4)(xy+z^2)^3}+\frac{y^3z^4x^3}{(y^4+z^4)(yz+x^2)^3}+\frac{z^3x^4y^3}{(z^4+x^4)(zx+y^2)^3}=3\frac{x^3x^4x^3}{(x^4+x^4)(x^2+x^2)^3}=3\frac{1}{16}=\frac{3}{16}$$

Comment: Well, I couldn't see a proof that disproved my solution...anyway if you substitute the solution $(x,x,x)$ in the symmetrical system, you can verify that it is a solution...

Comment: Well, I am not clear how your system is justified, for e.g. we can write an inequality e.g. $a+b+c \le 3 \max(a, b, c)$ with equality iff $a=b=c$, or a host of other such inequalities - why do you think all/any of these lead to the absolute maximum of $T$?

Comment: Perhaps I should add that you can also show the inequality $a+b+c \ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$ with equality iff $a=b=c$, and by your argument conclude this must be a minimum also! and hence $T$ is a constant!!  You see the contradiction?